# Custom HTML for ManyToMany Field in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am currently working on a form that displays information about a specific product on my website. Each price is represented by a *Price* object, and each *Item* has several *Price* objects associated with it. I have created a ModelForm to display the data in my *Item*, which works. However, when I try to display the ManyToMany field in my ModelForm, I get a small box that lists all of my *Price* objects. I need to display custom HTML for the *Price* objects so that I can have them interact with some JavaScript I have. Below is the code I have thus far:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    category    = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    prices      = models.ManyToManyField(Price, blank=True)
    images      = models.ManyToManyField(Image)
    runs        = models.ManyToManyField(ActivityRun, blank=True)
    date_added  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
    description = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE())

@login_required
def edit_item(request, item_id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=item_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ItemForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/items/")
    else:
        form = ItemForm(instance=item)

    return render(request, 'edit_item.html', {'form': form})
```

And the part of my template I am trying to display:

```
{% for price in form.prices %}
    <span class="price_box" style="width: 200px;">
        <a href="#" class="remove_price">x</a>{{ price.name }} ${{ price.price }}
    <input type="hidden" name="price_name" value="{{ price.name }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="price_cost" value="{{ price.price }}">
    </span>
{% endfor %}
```

I am not entirely sure how to go about accomplishing this . . .

More specifically, how do I change the HTML for the manytomany display in my form?

Comment: Use some Jquery plugin that customizes `<select>`. There are plenty of them, [this](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) for example. And no need to change server-side code.

Comment: @DrTyrsa while I think that would work, it seems kind of hackish. Surely there is a proper way to modify the HTML output of a ManyToMany field in django?

Comment: Custom widget can be an alternative, but there is no hackish is Jquery plugin. It is a proper way.

Comment: I'm looking at a custom widget. I'd just like to return the appropriate HTML from my server, without having to rely on JavaScript; what happens if the user has JS turned off? I still want my information to be displayed appropriately. I'm looking at custom widgets. What's the best way to get the ManyToMany to display custom HTML?

Comment: And that's why you need to use Jquery plugin. I JavaScript is disabled, user will get usual `<select>`. But if you want to use custom widget, it will also solve your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use an inline_modelformset to edit your prices. This will probably require you to change your Item model to not have a M2M to Price, but rather have Item as an FK to Price.

This way, you can use a custom form for Price, and have one or more instances of a PriceForm that will be automatically related to an Item. The formset will have the delete functionality as well, which you could handle via Ajax if you wish. You could also dynamically add/remove forms.

Hope that helps you out.